# create amazon cloudfront distribution not using amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am new to amazon cloudfront and learning about it. I want to create cloudfront distribution but not using amazon S3 bucket as origin domain name.

I want to use rails server as origin domain name.

I did some research online but i couldnt find any example

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up Amazon Cloudfront without S3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152830/setting-up-amazon-cloudfront-without-s3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can!

Simply create a new origin and enter the appropriate URL into the **Origin Domain Name** field. The pop-up help explains:

> Click in the field and specify the domain name for your origin - the Amazon S3 bucket or **web server** from which you want CloudFront to get your web content. To use a resource from a different AWS account, **type the domain name of the resource**. The files in your origin must be publicly readable.

While that field appears as a pull-down list of S3 buckets and Load Balancers, you can enter a custom domain, too.

From [Using Amazon EC2 or Other Custom Origins](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html):

> A **custom origin** is an HTTP server, for example, a web server. The HTTP server can be an Amazon EC2 instance or an HTTP server that you manage privately. When you use a custom origin, you specify the DNS name of the server, along with the HTTP and HTTPS ports and the protocol that you want CloudFront to use when fetching objects from your origin.